# Can I create an option name with hyphens in apache commons cli?

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I am trying to set Option name with hyphens in it like "source-files" using the Apache Commons CLI java library.

```
Option option = new Option("source-files", true, "List of source files")
```

I get this error,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: opt contains illegal character value '-'
at org.apache.commons.cli.OptionValidator.validateOption(OptionValidator.java:73)
at org.apache.commons.cli.Option.<init>(Option.java:123)
at org.apache.commons.cli.Option.<init>(Option.java:105)
```

Which means I cannot use an option name with a hyphen in it, which is the standard with unix commands. I noticed that [Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/index.html) documentation mentions a hyphenated option name in one their examples. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8):

You can only use `-` in the "long name":

```
options.addOption("S", "source-files", true, "List of source files")
```

If you want to only have the long name, you may need to use `OptionBuilder` (not sure).

Comment: You can just pass `null` as the short name, if you only want the long name.